# Solr : result optimization

Tags: solr

Currently when searching for "Iphone" in our solr -

Result are -

1. Iphone Cover
2. Iphone Cover
3. Iphone 7
4. Iphone 7s

Is there a way that the cover results are displayed only when solr input query has the word "Cover" in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `fieldType` use for the `field`(Field on which you are performing the search).

Change the `fieldType` for the the field as `String` if you want the exact match.

You can also use the '`KeywordTokenizerFactory`'

`KeywordTokenizerFactory` :-

Keyword Tokenizer does not split the input at all.
There is no processing in performed on the input string, and the entire string is kept as a single entity.
This doesn't actually do any tokenization. It returns the original text as one term.

Answer (score 0):

you are hitting the very typical problem of ecommerce sites: accessories products show up all over the place, clustering the results, when they are not usually the target of the user search (but sometimes they are!).

Ideal solution:

- you have some field like isAccessory, and boost it negatively, leaving the scoring to make the accessories be best matches when the user really searches for accessories. Or just don't apply the negative boost if you detect an accessory term in the query (coming up with that list is valuable, and not very hard: cover, case, charger...)
- this is not possible when you crawl your data etc

So, to fix this you can:

1. if you can come up with the training data, train a model in Solr, and set it as a [UpdateRequestProcessor](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7739), so you get isAccessory populated automatically as you index.
2. if you cannot do the above, as a last resort, you could negatively boost all 'accessory terms' when there is no accessory term in the query.